# Is there an error in the definitions described in the text?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Tao's Analysis II, bounded sets are defined as:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $Y \subseteq X$ be bounded iff for every $x \in X$ there exists a ball $B(x, r)$ of some finite radius r which contains Y. We call the metric space $(X, d)$ bounded if $X$ is bounded.

To me this seems to be a problematic definition, because suppose $X = [0, 2]$, and $Y = (0, 1)$, where it is obvious that both of these are bounded sets. However, for $x = 2$ there does not exist a ball $B(x, r)$ with finite non-negative $r$ that is in $X$ that will contain $Y$.

It seems that a definition that changes the universal part for an existential one would be correct, in the sense that there exists a ball with finite radius centered at some $x \in X$ that will contain the subset $Y$.

Additionally, Tao defines as totally bounded a space where for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $n$ and a finite number of balls $B(x^{1}, \epsilon) ... B(x^{n}, \epsilon)$ which cover X (i.e. X = $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B(x^{i}, \epsilon)$).

I find this one odd as well because it is one thing to cover X, which means that it will contain $X$, while it is another thing to be exactly equal to $X$. Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 4):

Your counterexample is incorrect.  Recall the definition of a ball in a metric space:

> *Definition:* Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.  For $x \in X$ and $r > 0$, the *ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$* is the set
> $$ B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < r \}. $$

Note that the ball, by definition, only contains points of $X$.  My guess is that you have it in your head that if $X = [0,2]$, then $X$ is "living inside of" the real number line, and so you are implicitly assuming that $B(2,r)$ is the interval $[2-r, 2+r]$ in the reals.  This not correct.  Rather, the ball of radius $r$ centered at $2$ is
$$ B(2,r) = (2-r,2+r) \cap [0,2] = \begin{cases} (2-r,2] & \text{if $r \le 2$,} \\ [0,2] & \text{if $r > 2$.} \end{cases} $$
So, take any $r > 2$.  Then $B(x,r) = [0,2] = X \subseteq Y$.

Similarly, if some collection of balls covers $X$, its union must, in fact, *be* $X$, since the balls only contain points of $X$.